# Como puedo hacer para que en java en un JTxtArea me de palabras claves en colores?

Tags: java, apache-netbeans

tengo un codigo de un compilador en java apache y quiero que cuando escriba algo como "printf" al darle espacio para escribir otra palabra me colore la palabra "printf" en otro color, y asi pueda asignar palabras claves y se visualicen en diferentes colores, lo intente con DocumentListener pero no me salio.

Comment: Hola Gutierrez Espinosa Jordan, bienvenida, creo que no es posible, estoy caso seguro que ni en **JTextField** ni en **JTextArea** puedes modificar caracteres individuales, no se si se puede en **JLabel**, sino toca usar Grafics.

Comment: Lo que usted necesita es un [JEditorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).